# Remove iframe horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, iframe

I want to remove the horizontal scrollbar in my iframe.  I just need a vertical scrollbar to view the lengthy contents. My code is

```
<iframe height='514' width='790' 
        marginwidth='0' marginheight='0' 
        frameborder='0' 
        overflow-y='scroll' 
        overflow-x='hidden'>
</iframe>
```

Anyone please solve my problem.  Advance Wishes.

Comment: can you please accept whichever answer you believe is the most correct here, or write your own and accept it?

Answer (score 51):

In the iframe page itself, add this:

```
body {
    overflow-x:hidden;
    height:100%; //optional, but it can't hurt.
}
```

Comment: "In the iframe page itself" this was a valuable piece of information that was missing from other answers, thanks!

Comment: @Shankaralwar: please accept this answer as solution, thanks for respecting this community and its rules

Comment: You have to put the comment optional into /* */ as that's how you comment things in CSS.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a browser that supports CSS3 you could use the overflow-x property.

```
#my-iframe
{
   overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/iframessi2.htm) is an IFrame-resize script.

However, if you use SSL then there is no way to use a script to communicate between the frame and the main window. It will give an "access denied". :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try setting scrolling attribute to "no"

```
<iframe scrolling="no" ..............> </iframe>
```

Answer (score -10):

The solution is:

```
style="overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:scroll;
```

in tag `<body>` of page included on `iframe`

<kbd>**[SEE THIS LINK PAGE](http://p2p.wrox.com/html-code-clinic/26921-disabling-horizontal-scrollbar-iframe.html)**</kbd>

Regards by Raffaele.

Comment: Please do not repeat the same answer, slightly modified, two years after an original answer has been provided.

Comment: I don't see this answer elsewhere? The provided answers did not work but this one did.